# jquery dropdown div disappears after leaving parent link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, drop-down-menu

I have the following html:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="has-drop-down">
        <a href="#" class="has-drop-down-a">Search</a>
            <div class="drop" style="display: none;">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <ul class="">
                            <li class="item-107"><a href="#">link1</a></li>
                            <li class="item-108"><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                            <li class="item-109"><a href="#">link3/a></li>
                            <li class="item-148"><a href="#">link4</a></li>
                            <li class="item-170"><a href="#">link5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***Unfortunately, the html has to have this structure (it's being dynamically created by a cms).***

I am using the following javascript to create the animation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('body').ready(function () {
            jQuery('.drop').slideUp(0);

            jQuery('.has-drop-down-a').hover(
                function () {
                    jQuery(this).siblings('.drop').slideDown(500);
                },

                function () {
                    jQuery(this).siblings('.drop').slideUp(500);
                }
            );
            });
</script>
```

CSS used:

```
#nav .drop {
   left: -9999px;
   padding: 27px 0 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
}
.drop:hover,
.drop ul:hover {
   position:relative;
   top:-1px;
   display: block !important;
}
#nav .drop > ul {
   position: relative;
}
#nav a {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 0 0 -27px;
   padding: 0 0 27px;
   position: relative;
}
```

***My issue*** is that after you leave the 'Search' link and move your cursor down to the dropdown ('drop' div) the dropdown disappears & then comes back.

There is a demo of this issue here if required http://goandco.w7.ext.starberry.com (I'll try to get this into a jsfiddle for future reference).

Comment: From the documentation: 'The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document...', so I'm guessing `$('body').ready` might give you unexpected results. Is there any reason you're attaching the `ready` event to `body`?

Comment: Thats my lack of knowledge of JS ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented by UweB should the `ready()` method be called on the `document`.

So change:

```
jQuery('body').ready(function () {
```

To:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
```

Also, delete the `left` and `top` position of `#nav .drop`.

You also might want to trigger the event on the list-item instead of the anchor. When triggering it on the list-item, the submenu will stay visible when you hover it. Otherwise, when you blur out the anchor, the submenu will slideup. You then need the `next()` method instead of the `sibling()` method.

Change your jQuery to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.drop').slideUp(0);

    jQuery('.has-drop-down').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.drop').slideDown(500);
    },
    function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.drop').slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/vaaf78z8/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var time=10000;
$('#Menu').mouseenter(function(){ 
    t=setTimeout("showMenu()",500);
});

$('#categoryMenu').mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t=setTimeout("hideMenu()",100);
});

function showMenu(){
    $('#megaDrop').fadeIn('fast');      
}

function hideMenu(){
    $('#megaDrop').hide('fast'); 
}

$('#megaDrop').hover(function(){
  clearTimeout(t);
},function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t=setTimeout("hideMenu()",100);

}
```

Use Timer to resolve your problem